# How to view web project on android

Tags: android, web, apk, tablet

I have a website project that I created using css/html/js and it's in a folder. It has several videos embedded into pages and as result the whole project weights around 700 Mb. I created it for a tablet so now I'm seeking the way to open it on an android tablet. I tried just copying the folder and using tablet Chrome to open index.html, but it displays some text instead. I also tried using PhoneGap to build an app, but it doesn't accept large projects. 
So is there really any way to achieve what I need? 
Turning it into an app would be preferred, but if there is any way just to open it in a browser, it would be helpful too. Where do I look and where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep your media files inside a directory on the sdcard. You can always access those media files present on the sdcard from your javacript code. In this way, you can easily create the apk by including html/css/js  and excluding the video files using the [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/).

Comment: So I just create a small apk and then unzip it, go inside and add those files inside apk and archive it back?

Comment: @NebularDust No, you'll have to create apk without the video files. Your apk will only contain the html/css/js code. APK wouldn't contain the videos. You'll have to write a javascript file that will provide the path of the media file present on the sdcard to your html video tag(assuming you are using video tag).

Comment: Ok I see and then I will just go into compiled apk and change links inside my project. And then archive it back to apk.

Comment: @NebularDust I guess you are not getting my point. You can't just change the link from the compiled apk and archive it back.

Comment: Maybe not, ok but then how do I provide any links to videofiles? Let's say I have a compiled apk, so how do I make a js file work with that apk and code inside of it and replace links to the different ones?

Comment: @NebularDust You can't make changes to the compiled apk. I was telling you to create the apk from your source code (using phonegap).You have mentioned in your question that you already have the source code and therefore you can easily add or edit files.

Comment: Ok, correct me if I'm wrong. First I remove video files from the project. Then I edit links in the project so they actually look something like /mnt/sdcard/video.mp4 for example. Then I compile that apk and upload it to the tablet. Then I place video files in /mnt/sdcard and then when I run an apk, it will link to files as needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96406/discussion-between-rahul-chaurasia-and-nebular-dust).

Answer (score 0):

In xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Class file

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
            private WebView webView;

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.webview);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            String url = "www.google.com"; // Give here hosted project url
            webView.loadUrl(url);
        }

        public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // This is used for finished on particular url
                if (url.contains("http://www.google.com/")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("responseurl", url);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);              
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is that exactly, should I just create index.xml file in my directory where I have index.html? And what is class file?

Comment: String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
webView.loadUrl(url); Url is your hosted project like:- www.google.com

Comment: In your scenario, like Rahul said, "you have keep media files on SD card"  & make build with PhoneGap.

Comment: And how do I change those links to sd card paths? Or I should do it before compiling apk?